How to update all even rows using Javascript
For example with a div element, this code works:
function col() {
  document.getElementById('myID').style.backgroundColor = // ...

How can I do this for all even rows? This does not work:
function col() {
  document.querySelectorAll("tr:nth-child(even)").style.backgroundColor = // ... 


The reason the code document.querySelectorAll("tr:nth-child(even)") doesn't work is because document.querySelectorAll() returns a NodeList, which is a collection of elements, not a single node as it is case with document.getElementById. You cannot directly set the style of a COLLECTION of elements. Instead, you need to loop through each element in the NodeList and apply the style individually.
This might help
function col() {
  const evenRows = document.querySelectorAll("tr:nth-child(even)");
  
  // Loop through each row and apply the background color
  evenRows.forEach(row => {
    row.style.backgroundColor = "yourColorHere"; 
  });
}


happy to read your opinion. but not working the above.

Can you send me your code so I can check it out?

how to send the code ? can you pass your email ? or how i can send it to you ?

Antonija can you send a hi / hai / hello to kkvbsuresh[at]live[dot]com

Antonija - collect your email from your website and send the code to you now. check your email and reply there.

@varghese I replied to your email. Talk to you there

The issue is because querySelectorAll() returns a Collection of elements, not a single Element. Therefore you need to loop over them all and set their background individually:
document.querySelectorAll("tr:nth-child(even)").forEach(tr => tr.style.backgroundColor = '#C00');

Here's some further reading for you on this subject.
With that being said, you should not be using JS to update the UI. Use CSS instead, where possible.
tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #C00;
}


happy to read your opinion. but not working the above. can't use css directly for the needs.

Rory McCrossan - How to write the code to apply to all class say 'class-e' using

document.querySelectorAll(".class-e").style.backgroundColor = '#C00'); )                          2) document.getElementsByClassName("class-e").style.backgroundColor = '#C00'); Can you help me ?


It works absolutely fine in isolation: https://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/poakcumd/. Check the console for errors, and check that the HTML for your table is valid.

Rory McCrossan - it's fine. Anyhow can you provide with a solution for the way with class  selector method as well ?

The exact same way. Just change tr:nth-child(even) to your target class: https://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/poakcumd/1/

Rory McCrossan - cheers. i use    and the relating script is function rgb() {
const bgColor = rgb(${document.getElementById("red").value});
document.querySelectorAll(".odd").forEach((odd) => {
odd.style.backgroundColor = bgColor;
});
}
rgb(); is working. the class apply to a table and few divisions. can you help me ?
